# Gcloud error… glcloud crashed (BadStatusLine): ''

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, pdo, google-cloud-platform

Usually I don't have any problem with gcloud commands. As one who only uses when updating my website my exposure is with one command:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

When gettings the error shown in the title it is suggested that I run 'gcloud info --run-diagnostics'. When run I get the following result:

```
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.
Reachability Check passed.
Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).
Property diagnostic detects issues that may be caused by properties.
Checking hidden properties...done.
ERROR: Hidden Property Check failed.
The following hidden properties have been set:
[compute/gce_metadata_read_timeout_sec]
Properties files
User: /tmp/tmp.PSJvG9V1wZ/configurations/config_cloudshell-19904
Installation: /google/google-cloud-sdk/properties
ERROR: Property diagnostic failed (0/1 checks passed).
```

Outside of that I don't have much exposure to gcloud commands. Now the error occurred after I setup a MySQL instance on my GAE(Google app engine). The question then becomes why this would cause that and how can I fix it. Or could have caused the issue through changing the way my code connects to the database? If that's is a possible problem here's that code:

[image: My GAE MySQL connection]

Comment: Dang! Thanks brrro. I'm glad it was that simple! Write it as the answer and I'll mark it as correct! :C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this issue after waking up my laptop from Hibernate mode and reconnecting to the cloud shell. The issue was resolved simply by closing the cloud shell tab on Chrome and initiating another shell from a new tab. :)

Comment: tks, have the same problem, create new shell solved

Answer (score 1):

I encountered  the same issue as described in here. https://github.com/TestArmada/flank/issues/307

Seems problem with Flank.

Restarting your workstation or re-run the following command

```
$ gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```